# Multiple Grunt tasks not found

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to build a yeoman generator and using the tutorial as a guide
http://yeoman.io/generators.html#writing-your-first-generator

I copied the Gruntfile.js from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenplusplus/5647725) referenced and put it in my generator's template directory. When I generate the project, I run

```
 npm install && bower install
```

then

```
 grunt test
```

> > Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?
> >          Warning: Task "concurrent:test" not found. Use --force to continue.

```
 Aborted due to warnings.


 Execution Time (2014-01-10 16:19:20 UTC)
 loading tasks  3ms
 ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 50%
 test           2ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
 Total 6ms
```

It is not clear to me why Grunt concurrent:test is not found. Grunt finds the clean:test task. I tried commenting the concurrent task and none of the other tasks were found for "test" except "clean". Here is the task list

grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
       ]);

Good point [jakerella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1985406/jakerella) I see now I was using different grunt file in my yeoman generator then I intended. When I replace Gruntfile.js with the one from the gist referenced in the yeoman tutorial, I get the same issue with a different task. Its says "watch" is not found.

```
$ ls node_modules/
bower                   grunt-contrib-compass           grunt-contrib-jshint            grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs
connect-livereload          grunt-contrib-concat            grunt-contrib-jst           grunt-usemin
grunt                   grunt-contrib-connect           grunt-contrib-livereload        load-grunt-tasks
grunt-bower-requirejs           grunt-contrib-copy          grunt-contrib-requirejs         matchdep
grunt-connect-proxy         grunt-contrib-cssmin            grunt-contrib-uglify            moment
grunt-contrib-clean         grunt-contrib-htmlmin           grunt-open              time-grunt
grunt-contrib-coffee            grunt-contrib-imagemin          grunt-regarde
$ grunt server
>> Local Npm module "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
$
```

Comment: The only task I see in that gist that is referenced in your `test` multi-task is `connect`... you'll need to provide us with your actual Gruntfile in order for us to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some work at identifying dependencies, I was able to get this to work once I copied the entire foundation app directory and then used the foundation5 generator's index.js list of files to copy from the template directory as a guide to additional resources that were required by my generator. I think this may be a helpful way for anyone trying to repurpose existing generators and help identify Grunt dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by running:
`npm install grunt-x --save-dev` replacing `x` with the name of the missing task repeatedly until done.

Incidentally I has first tried `npm install -g grunt-x` and that didn't work.

Comment: I installed with grunt-... libraries still no luck, tried both, global and local installation, any idea?